# I have a ios crash log and Im on windows and can't read it

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am on windows and I am an apple developer. Quite the match right. Well, I have a huge bug on my unity game and I received a crash log file. But, only one problem. I can't understand it. I do not have xcode. I have the file itself and it says it's a bugtype 309. I can't symbolicate it either. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you.

here's a little snippet, if anyone can help me out.

"ime" : 7500, "procRole" : "Foreground", "version" : 2, "userID" : 501, "deployVersion" : 210, "modelCode" : "iPhone11,8", "coalitionID" : 916, "osVersion" : { "isEmbedded" : true, "train" : "iPhone OS 17.0", "releaseType" : "User", "build" : "21A329" }, "captureTime" : "2023-09-19 09:56:34.6392 -0700", "codeSigningMonitor" : 1, "incident" : "A3F5FA70-7C68-498A-A534-A55E23E88263", "pid" : 903, "cpuType" : "ARM-64", "roots_installed" : 0, "bug_type" : "309", "procLaunch" : "2023-09-19 09:56:15.5922 -0700", "procStartAbsTime" : 180831869743, "procExitAbsTime" : 181288438801, "procName" : "El", "procPath" : "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC7A3162-12FE-4340-B40A-172D8C554969/EndlessFall.app/EndlessFall", "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.9","CFBundleVersion":"0.9.18","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.Bl","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"1a"}, "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"641","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"5557A5A3-438E-4341-9D8D-3256CE7DDCCD","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"859958770"}, "parentProc" : "launchd", "parentPid" : 1,"

I am on windows 11, and have searched up ways to open it in here on windows. I originally thought what caused it was an infinite debug loop in the code, which I did find and resolve and this came up again. I believe it might be the advertisment on it since it is a third party software.
I am debating on getting a vm and downlaoding xcode there and then symbolicating it through there.
But before that, I want to see what experts like you all would suggest.

thank you so much fopr your tiume and patience. apologies for spellnig mistakes

Comment: You haven't added anything of the stack trace

Comment: what's the stack trace? apologies but this is my first time dealing with this

Comment: If you search the web for "stack trace" you'll get plenty of information on what it is

Comment: However, even if you include it, it's unlikely that anyone here will be able to debug it, especially if it isn't symbolicated, like you mentioned.

Comment: I wasn't provided a stack trace, just a unsymbolicated crash log txt file.
thanks for your time and patience

Comment: what would you suggest i do then?

Comment: If the crash log doesn't contain a stack trace (which is very odd), there's nothing that you can do

Comment: If i can i get it symbolicated, my cousin has a mac laptop. will you help me?

Comment: If you don't have a stack trace, there's nothing to symbolicate. You said you don't have a stack trace. If you _do_ have a stack trace and can symbolicate it, then you should start investigating the line that causes the issue and update your question with that information. Then, anyone here on SO may be able to offer some advice.

Comment: @jnpdx I wasn't able to symbolicate it, they didn't send in it fully but it's irrelevant now.

Comment: @jnpdx I've symbolicated it, im going to make a new post about it. mind lending a hand?